# my form is not validate with jquery validate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

my form is not validate with jquery validate function

```js
<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Referrals | India</title>

    <meta name='description' content='At Veepal, we work on web development and web application development projects based on the proven Project Development Methodology (SDLC).'/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.veepal.com/why-veepal" />

    <meta name='robots' content='noodp'/>
    <meta name='google-site-verification' content='KpLSxTAPqnxGuygv1GajjqhDjAgL6skG0f47PE7n3Oo' />
    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="5D74C2D02269A257714752651F59C85A" />
    <meta name="alexaVerifyID" content="0zTAiY6o4WrSt4zIb8iTaapixEE" />
    <meta name="avgthreatlabs-verification" content="3ccfecf442587cd1d7a938645f6adb99cbb6e1c5" />
    <meta name="p:domain_verify" content="a4b905b4d212fdffdbe48e61ff04ba06"/>
    <link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/+Veepal/posts"/>
    <link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/102356317964360660690"/> 

    <meta property="og:title" content="Offshore Development | Web Design &amp; Web  Application Development | India"/>  
    <meta property="og:description" content="At Veepal, we work on web development and web application development projects based on the proven Project Development Methodology (SDLC)."/> 
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/> 
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.veepal.com/"/> 
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Veepal IT Services"/> 
    <meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/Software.Development.India"/> 
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="146507655407127" />
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/> 
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@veepal"/> 
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@veepal"/>
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Veepal IT Services">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->

    <!-- CSS for Nivo Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/themes/default/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/nivo-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/nivo-style.css">

    <!-- css site style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/buttons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/mediaquery.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout-ie9.css">
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout-ie8.css">
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/form1.css">
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/form.css">-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-20533631-1', 'veepal.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
-->  
<!--<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
-->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
      $("#myform").validate({
           rules: {
                    username: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                         },
                    phoneno : "required",
                    referrals : "required"
                    },
            messages: {
                username: "Please enter your name",
                email: "Please enter your email",
                phoneno : "Please enter your phone number",
                referrals :"Please enter details"
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });
</script>

</head>
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="myform" novalidate="novalidate">

                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" 

width="100%" style="padding-left:10px;">

              <!--<tr>
                <td class="contact-form-heading" colspan="3">Hire Our 

Professionals</td>
              </tr>-->
              <tr id="response">
                <td colspan="3"></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td width="25%" class="contact-form">Name: (required)</td>

              </tr>
              <tr><td width="70%" class="contact-text-form"><input type="text" class="contact-form-filds" name="username" id="username" width="50%" required></td></tr>

              <tr>
            <td class="contact-form">E-mail: (required)</td>
                </tr>

           <tr> <td width="70%" class="contact-text-form"><input type="email" class="contact-form-filds" name="email" id="email"></td>
          </tr>

              <tr>
                <td class="contact-form">Telephone: (required)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td width="70%" class="contact-text-form"><input type="text" class="contact-form-filds" name="phoneno" id="phoneno"></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td class="contact-form">Details of Company / Person being referred: (required)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td class="contact-text-form"><textarea name="referrals" class="contact-form-filds2" id="referrals" cols="1000" rows="3" ></textarea></td>  
              </tr>

                <tr>


                    <td width="75"><input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" class="btnsubmit"></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

              </tr>
             </table>
    </form>

            </form>
```

My form is not validate with jquery validate() function.The error is TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function.jquery validation plugin is not working after adding the script in the head tag.

Comment: we can't assume whats wrong without code.

Comment: how to add code file?

Comment: Paste your coding in your question

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: My error is:TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
 

$(

"#myform").validate({

Comment: i see the jquery validated plugin placed 4 times in your page why is that?

Comment: I got the error again and again so i have tried different version of jqurry plugin

Comment: Which version should I use for this validate jquery

Comment: the latest and use only one jquery library compatible with it

Comment: which one should i try?

Comment: your code works fine. There must be an error in the js above where you are loading in the validation script. you have 2 jquery scripts uncommented/loaded, try removing one.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have added only these three js.But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add "html" tag before "head" tag and keep your form in body tag.
It will perfectly validates your form